# Meteor http.call does not work correctly on server

Tags: meteor

In Meteor, I am doing requests to an external API (this one - http://sciencesoft.at/latex/?lang=en).

When performing a Meteor.http.call from client (console) it works correctly. When doing the same from the server, Meteor.http.call seems to send a call with empty body (ignores its options argument).

The complete and specific code which I use is written below. Here I try to point out the principle of the problem:

On the client (in console) this works fine:

```
Meteor.http.call('PUT', 'http://sciencesoft.at/latex', {content: sentxml}, function (e,r) {console.log(r.content)}); //asynchronously
```

Here sentxml contains a body of the xml request (as specified in the docs of the external API).

On the server, I have a Meteor.method which contains:

```
return Meteor.http.call('PUT', 'http://sciencesoft.at/latex', {content: sentxml}); //synchronously
```

When I do in console:

```
Meteor.call('myMethod', sentxml, function (e,r) {          
  console.log(r.content);                              
});
```

I get back a xml response which contains an error (the same error as if I omitted the third argument of Meteor.http.call() in my method).

---

To be more specific, the complete code follows.

When I do in console:

```
src= 'ABCD'; // I want to get png of this text.
latexsrc = '\\documentclass[12pt]{article}\\pagestyle{empty}\\begin{document}'+ src +'\\end{document}'; // minimalistic LaTeX source code
sentxml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><latex ochem="false"><dev dpi="120">png16m</dev><src><![CDATA['+latexsrc+']]></src><embeddedData>true</embeddedData></latex>'; // body of the xml request as described in the docs of http://sciencesoft.at/latex/?lang=en
Meteor.http.call('PUT','http://sciencesoft.at/latex', {content: sentxml}, function (e,r) {console.log(r.content)});
```

then sentxml is correctly sent to the specified url and I get a correct xml response, which contains the data I requested.

However, I would like to do the http call from server. I have an almost identical code as above inside a Meteor method:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    getLatexImgData: function (src) {
      this.unblock();    
      var latexsrc = '\\documentclass[12pt]{article}\\pagestyle{empty}\\begin{document}'+ src +'\\end{document}';
      var sentxml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><latex ochem="false"><dev dpi="120">png16m</dev><src><![CDATA['+latexsrc+']]></src><embeddedData>true</embeddedData></latex>';
      var result = Meteor.http.call('PUT','http://sciencesoft.at/latex', {content: sentxml});      
      return result;    
    }
  });
}
```

When I now do in console:

```
src = 'ABCD';
Meteor.call('getLatexImgData', src, function (e,r) {          
  console.log(r.content);                              
});
```

then r.content contains a xml response with the error message "Element 'src' is empty! No LaTeX source available!" (the same message as if the http.call was made with empty body).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a problem with your API, not with Meteor.

This http call seems to work for me (server):

```
Meteor.http.call('PUT','http://sciencesoft.at/latex', {content: sentxml, params: {src: latexsrc}});
```

Comment: Thanks, the params option did the trick. But why it is not needed when doing the http call asynchronously from client?

Comment: The call from the client doesn't work at all for me: `Origin http://domainname.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`, try with the meteor.com client javascript console for instance.

Comment: The Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue is because of Cross-site HTTP requests security setting. To get rid of the error while developing, I run chrome with `--disable-web-security` option.